# Obtener los valores de una lista con diccionarios

Tags: python-3.7

```py
dict = [{
    "a: "01",
    "b": "123.com",
    "c": "PRID01",
    "InstId": "PRID0000001-1",
    "Status": "approved"
  },{
    "a": "02",
    "b": "123.com",
    "c": "PRID02",
    "InstId": "PRID0000001-2",
    "Status": "approved"
  }]
```

De cada elemento de la lista quiero obtener los valores de InstId y almacenarlos en una lista nueva, se me ocurria algo asi pero me falla al acceder a los elementos de la lista

```py
    listaNueva=[]
    for x in dict['InstID']:
      listanueva.append[x]
    print(listanueva)
```

Comment: Sería preferible si usaras el formato de código también para el contenido del diccionario, ya que así sería más legible. También nota que 'dict' es un tipo de dato en sí mismo, por lo que no es adecuado como nombre de variable. Además, lo que presentas en el ejemplo es una lista, no un diccionario. Tendrías que iterar sobre cada elemento de la lista, y dentro del bucle obtener el valor correspondiente a la clave que te interesa.

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de acciones, aunque lo normal sea hacer simplemente un bucle for, te recomiendo usar [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html), librería que maneja infinidad de funciones útiles para el manejo de datos y que te será muy útil en el futuro.

Lo primero de todo es definir el DataFrame que vamos a utilizar:

```
import pandas

dictionary = [{ "a": "01", "b": "123.com", "c": "PRID01", "InstId": "PRID0000001-1", "Status": "approved" },{ "a": "02", "b": "123.com", "c": "PRID02", "InstId": "PRID0000001-2", "Status": "approved" }]
data_frame=pandas.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

Esto creará una tabla cuyos títulos de las filas serán los índices de las mismas y los títulos de las columnas serán las keys del DataFrame (como esta función ya muestra la indexación de las columnas de manera automática, podrías evitarte todas las "a"-s de los diccionarios).
A continuación, iremos editando el data_frame para quedarnos únicamente con los valores que nos interesan.

```
valores_InstId=data_frame["InstId"]  # Esto retornará una nueva tabla con los valores en la columna "InstId"
```

Ahora que ya tenemos los valores "InstId" de todos los diccionarios, solo queda transformar la nueva tabla a lista, y esto se puede hacer de dos maneras:

```
valores_InstId=valores_InstId.tolist()
```

o mediante:

```
valores_InstId=list(valores_InstId.values)
```

Ya acabado, el código final quedaría muy corto:

```
import pandas

dictionary = [{ "a": "01", "b": "123.com", "c": "PRID01", "InstId": "PRID0000001-1", "Status": "approved" },{ "a": "02", "b": "123.com", "c": "PRID02", "InstId": "PRID0000001-2", "Status": "approved" }]
data_frame=pandas.DataFrame(dictionary)
valores_InstId=data_frame["InstId"].tolist()
```

Si te ha parecido interesante, te dejo [aquí un link](https://mlcourse.ai/book/topic01/topic01_pandas_data_analysis.html) con un tutorial extenso que te enseñará la aplicación y utilidad de pandas a la hora de manejar grandes cantidades de datos, así como su compatibilidad con otras librerías

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores.

1. Cuando declaras la lista de diccionario, pones el cierre de la comilla de la "a" después de los dos puntos.
2. Cuando iteras en el `for` debes obtener de cada diccionario la clave `'InstId'`, No evaluar la lista completa en ese valor.
3. Tienes un typo, es `'InstId'` no `'InstID'`

Tu código, corregido, quedaría así:

```
dictionary = [{ "a": "01", "b": "123.com", "c": "PRID01", "InstId": "PRID0000001-1", "Status": "approved" },{ "a": "02", "b": "123.com", "c": "PRID02", "InstId": "PRID0000001-2", "Status": "approved" }]

listaNueva=[]
for x in dictionary:
  listaNueva.append(x['InstId'])
print(listaNueva)
```

Comment: primer **Gran** error, usar el nombre de una clase como variable. Por otra parte una list comprehension también es buena opción quedando `lista_nueva = [x["InstId"] for x in diccionario]; print(lista_nueva)`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes no es un diccionario, sino una lista de diccionarios. Igual conservare el nombre `dicc`.

Lo pedido se puede hacer con comprensión de listas:

```
lista = [x["InstId"] for x in dicc]
```

que es una forma compacta para crear listas. La expresión anterior es equivalente a:

```
lista = []
for x in dicc:
    lista.append(x["InstId"])
```

#### Demo

```
dicc = [{
    "a": "01",
    "b": "123.com",
    "c": "PRID01",
    "InstId": "PRID0000001-1",
    "Status": "approved"},
    {
    "a": "02",
    "b": "123.com",
    "c": "PRID02",
    "InstId": "PRID0000001-2",
    "Status": "approved"
  }]
lista = [x["InstId"] for x in dicc]
print(lista)
```

produce:

```
['PRID0000001-1', 'PRID0000001-2']

Process finished with exit code 0
```